# How to solve this sequence, involving trigonometry?

Tags: sequences-and-series

The first two terms of a geometric progression are $1$ and $13 \tan 2θ$ respectively, where $0 < θ < 12 \pi$.

Find the set of values of θ for which the progression is convergent.

Don't know how to start solving this.

Comment: See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_series#Proof_of_convergence

Answer (score 1):

hint:

the ratio of the sequence is 
$$
r=\frac{a_2}{a_1}=13 \tan(2\theta)
$$
and the sequence is convergent (to $0$) iff $-1<r<1$. Can you do from this solving two trigonometric inequalities?